# iPhone to iPhone communication

Tags: iphone, swift, mobile, communication

I am developing two apps in swift which should communicate with another iPhone device and waiting for their response over Global.

I am using remote push notification and it's working fine, but its not receiving notification while the app in foreground state and has some push notification related issues.

If I used web service for sending and receiving. My app gets struck due to the lag response

**Is any method available for iPhone communication over internet without using APNs?**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can use [MultipeerConnectivityFramework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/), which has support for discovering services provided by nearby iOS devices using infrastructure Wi-Fi networks, peer-to-peer Wi-Fi, and Bluetooth personal area networks and subsequently communicating with those services by sending message-based data, streaming data, and resources (such as files).

I am adding sample code [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/MultipeerGroupChat/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013691), it is an example application which builds on the Multipeer Connectivity framework for discovering, connecting, and sharing data between "nearby" peers. This application uses framework based UI for connecting to local peers and the framework convenience API for exhanging text messages and image resources between devices.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I need to communicate with worldwide.

Comment: @ManikandanD, you can use `CocoaAsyncSocket` to establish socket connection between devices.  Here is [code](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket)